# Does a MaaS region or Cluster controller going down mean the provisioned servers go down or only that new servers will not be provisioned?

Tags: server, maas

This is a followup question to my [previous question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/345638/does-maas-provide-options-for-high-availability-or-redundancy).

I'm trying to understand the implications if a region or cluster controller goes down.

So, does a MaaS region or Cluster controller going down mean the provisioned servers go down or only that new servers will not be provisioned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that no new machines can be acquired, provisioned or enlisted.  Existing machines that are allocated and running are not affected.

If it was only a cluster that went down then only that cluster's machines are affected.